# Customised jQuery input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a input that when I press up and down, it increment/decrement 0.001 and when I press left/right, it increment/decrement 0.01. However, when I click left a few times I'll get something like 0.060000000000000005 instead of just 0.06. How do I fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/xhpjafhn/3/

### HTML

```
<div class="display" id="out">test</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">value:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="Number" step='0.001' value="0.00" id="in"></input>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
function getLocalDecimalSeparator() {
    var n = 1.1;
    return n.toLocaleString().substring(1,2);
}

function parseLocalFloat(num) {
    return Number(num.replace(getLocalDecimalSeparator(), '.'));
}

//var x = document.getElementById('in');
$('#in').on("change", function(){
    var x = parseLocalFloat($(this).val());
    $('#out').html(x);
});

$('#in').on("keydown", function(e){

    if(e.keyCode == 37){
        $(this).val(+$(this).val() + +0.01);
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 39){
        $(this).val(+$(this).val() - +0.01);
    }

    $(this).change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this behaviour is caused to floating point operations precision / errors ([wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding)).

What you can do is enforce a fixed number of decimals (so basically, round the result). You can use the `toFixed()` method to choose the exact number of digits or the `toPrecision()` method to choose how many significant digits you want displayed. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that the java floating point calculation is not always accurate and there are precision errors.

Now it depends on what kind of calculations you’re doing.

**If you just
   don’t want to see all those extra decimal places: simply format your
   result rounded to a fixed number of decimal places when displaying
   it.**

```
function getLocalDecimalSeparator() {
    var n = 1.1;
    return n.toLocaleString().substring(1,2);
}

function parseLocalFloat(num) {
    return Number(num.replace(getLocalDecimalSeparator(), '.'));
}

$('#in').on("change", function(){
    var x = parseLocalFloat($(this).val());

    //Round it to 3 decimal places
    $('#out').html(Math.round(x * 1000) / 1000);


});

$('#in').on("keydown", function(e){

    if(e.keyCode == 37){
        $(this).val(+$(this).val() + +0.01);
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 39){
        $(this).val(+$(this).val() - +0.01);
    }

    $(this).change();
});
```

**If you have no decimal datatype available, work with integers (look at the example).**

```
function getLocalDecimalSeparator() {
    var n = 1.1;
    return n.toLocaleString().substring(1,2);
}

function parseLocalFloat(num) {
    return Number(num.replace(getLocalDecimalSeparator(), '.'));
}

$('#in').on("change", function(){

    //Display as float
    var x = parseLocalFloat($(this).val())/1000;

    $('#out').html(x);
});

$('#in').on("keydown", function(e){

    if(e.keyCode == 37){

        //Add integer
        $(this).val(+$(this).val() + +1);

    }
    if(e.keyCode == 39){

        //Add integer
        $(this).val(+$(this).val() - +1);

    }

    $(this).change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this part of code insted of your

```
$('#in').on("keydown", function(e){

    if(e.keyCode == 37){
        $(this).val(+$(this).val() +0.01);
        return false;
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 39){
        $(this).val(+$(this).val() - 0.01);
        return false;
    }

    $(this).change();
});
```